# Watching a subset of a full dataset in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a view with a list (a table) and a graph over the same dataset. In my Angular controller i have

```
$scope.prices = [{'country': 'Denmark', price: 200.00}, {'country': 'Sweden', price: 180.00}];
```

In the html I then use ng-repeat to render this as a table. No problem so far. I then use angular-chart.js to render a graph, and have the following code

```
<canvas id="launchSequence" class="chart chart-bar"
              chart-data="graphData" chart-labels="graphLabels">
</canvas>
```

This javascript library expect $scope.graphData and $scope.graphLabels in this format

```
$scope.graphData = [[200.00, 180.00]];
$scope.graphLabels = ['Denmark', 'Sweden'];;
```

My question is, how do I make it so that changes to $scope.prices, like changing a price of a country, is reflected in $scope.graphData and the graph is updated?

I have tried several approaches, like trying to make a

```
$scope.$watch('rices', function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {//Change $scope.graphLabels});
```

But it appears that a change to one price inside $scope.prices, does not trigger the watch function.

Being a AngularJS newbie, I wonder what the correct way to do this with AngularJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the third optional parameter in [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), it uses `angular.equals()`

```
 $scope.$watch('rices', function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {}, true);
```